# Why are my headers null after a POST?

Tags: java, rest, file-upload, jersey, jetty

I'll lay down my code first:  Note:  I also have log output at the bottom of the question.

Server Side:

```
@Post
@Consumes("application/octet-stream")
public Representation post(InputStream zip, @HeaderParam(value = "Content-Disposition") HttpHeaders headers) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(headers); //Prints null - want the header to not be null here
    String uploadedFileLocation = getStartingDir() + "/" + "abc.zip";
    writeToFile(zip, uploadedFileLocation); 
    return new StringRepresentation("Uploaded!");
}
```

Client Side:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/server/upload";

    Client client = Client.create();
    WebResource service = client.resource(BASE_URI);
    client.setChunkedEncodingSize(1024);
    client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter());


    File zip = new File("C:/Users/sdery/Desktop/abc.zip");

    InputStream fileInStream = new FileInputStream(zip);
    String sContentDisposition = "attachment; filename=\"" + zip.getName()+"\"";     
    ClientResponse response = service.header("Authorization", "Basic xxx=").header("Content-Disposition", (Object)sContentDisposition).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).post(ClientResponse.class, fileInStream);     
    System.out.println("Response Status : " + response.getEntity(String.class));

}
```

First off, the file transfer works, I'm happy.  However, I would like to get the headers on the server side so I don't have to hard code the file name.  Any ideas as to why it is comin' up null?  Does it have to do with me using `ClientResponse` instead of `ClientRequest`?

```
Jul 31, 2013 8:44:12 AM com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 1 * Client out-bound request
1 > POST http://localhost:8080/server/upload
1 > Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="abc.zip"
1 > Authorization: Basic xxx=
1 > Content-Type: application/octet-stream

(zip bytes)

INFO: 1 * Client in-bound response
1 < 200
1 < Date: Wed, 31 Jul 2013 12:44:12 GMT
1 < Date: Wed, 31 Jul 2013 12:44:12 GMT
1 < Vary: Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Accept
1 < Content-Length: 88
1 < Set-Cookie: rememberMe=deleteMe; Path=/server; Max-Age=0; Expires=Tue, 30-Jul-2013   12:44:12 GMT
1 < Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
1 < Accept-Ranges: bytes
1 < Server: Restlet-Framework/2.0.4
1 < Real-Token: bar
1 < 
Uploaded!
```

From the log output, it seems that the header containing `Content-Disposition` is there.  Does this mean I should be able to retrieve the value from the server side code?

Comment: Turn on logging (`client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter());`) and verify that the request going out actually contains the header. Your use of `ClientResponse` is correct because the _result_ of your POST is a response not a request.

Comment: I have the header in the filter.  I will add it to my question above, or in a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're parameter is of the wrong type.  You should declare the parameter as a String.  HttpHeaders is for getting all the headers and is annotated with a @Context.  @HttpParam can only be converted to a limited number of types.

From the Jersey documentation for HeaderParam.

> Binds the value(s) of a HTTP header to a resource method parameter, resource class field, or resource class bean property. A default value can be specified using the DefaultValue annotation. The type T of the annotated parameter, field or property must either:

```
Be a primitive type
Have a constructor that accepts a single String argument
Have a static method named valueOf or fromString that accepts a single String argument (see, for example, Integer.valueOf(String))
Be List<T>, Set<T> or SortedSet<T>, where T satisfies 2 or 3 above. The resulting collection is read-only.
```

So you're code would be more like

```
@Post
@Consumes("application/octet-stream")
public Representation post(InputStream zip, @HeaderParam(value = "Content-  Disposition") String contentDisposition) throws Throwable {
   System.out.println(contentDisposition); 
   String uploadedFileLocation = getStartingDir() + "/" + "abc.zip";
   writeToFile(zip, uploadedFileLocation); 
   return new StringRepresentation("Uploaded!");
}
```

Comment: I am getting `null` when using String and even Object.  I used `@HeaderParam(value = "Content-  Disposition") String contentDisposition`, which is somehow still `null`.

Comment: @StephenD You might try injecting an instance of HttpHeaders using Context annotation, and then printing out all the headers.  I've not used the client library with Jersey, but it looks like you are correctly sending the header.  Then make sure the spelling of the headers match.

Comment: For some reason, even grabbing it with `@Context` is `null`.  I've tried renaming things around with no luck still.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I apologize that my solution is from a JavaScript/PHP reference and not Java, but I believe your solution may be similar.

Add a new header named 'X-FILENAME' and set the name of your file as the header data.  I believe your code would look something like this:

```
ClientResponse response = service.header("X-FILENAME", "abc.zip");
```

Then, on your server, you should be able to retrieve that header param (In PHP it is the `$_SERVER` global, it looks like in yours it may be `@HeaderParam`).

Also, for reference just in case this applies to you, in PHP when you retrieve the header param you need to use a modified param name by adding 'HTTP_' to the front and changing all dashes to underscores like this 'HTTP_X_FILENAME'.  So on the client you sent 'X-FILENAME' while on the server you retrieve that same value with 'HTTP_X_FILENAME'.

I hope this leads you in the right direction.

Comment: I appreciate your response.  I have made edits that reflect your input, no luck however.